# How to connect over fastboot to Galaxy A50?

Tags: adb, usb, fastboot, rom, usb-drivers

I'm on ubuntu 22.04 and I can connect over adb to my Samsung Galaxy A50, and do

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

it reboots to bootloader mode, but I can't use `fastboot devices`, it returns empty.

Other phones work in this computer.

`lsusb` shows

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)
```

All tutorials talk about a Windows driver, but what do I do for ubuntu?

Comment: Most Samsung devices don't have a real fastboot/bootloader mode. The lower layers of Samsung device are just a bit different. Also "Download mode" is also not fastboot mode you could better call it "Odin mode" (or "Heimdall mode" as you are on Linux).

Comment: @Robert oh ok. Is there an open source client for odin mode?

Comment: Search for Samsung + Heimdall and you will find what you need.

Comment: @Rafaelo see our [heimdall tag wiki](/tags/heimdall/info) ;) P: [here](https://github.com/amo13/Heimdall) is a more up-to-date fork of it.